# How does (this) work in this code, javascript?

Tags: javascript, logic, this

I'm trying to make a simple To Do app as an assignment, in this code a checkbox is created every time a button is clicked and a counter keeps track of unchecked checkboxes, so I made a simple if-else statement.. if the box is clicked decrease unchecked counter and vice versa.. my problem is with `this`, here the code that I feel it's logical because `validate()` is already an attribute of the checkbox it shouldn't have to pass `this`

```js
const aCheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
aCheckbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
aCheckbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'validate()');

function validate() {
    if(this.checked) {
        console.log('Checked');
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work, I tried the following code and it does work, the difference is that `this` is passed when `validate()` is invoked while the first code `this` is called in `validate()`, so why the first code isn't working even though the function is called within the checkbox?

```js
const aCheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
aCheckbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
aCheckbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'validate(this)');

function validate(x){
    if(x.checked){
        console.log('Checked');
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(this)`

Comment: You should NOT be using setAttribute to add event listeners.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, can you explain why or refer me to page explaining this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript `this` keyword refers to the object it belongs to.

It has different values depending on where it is used:

In a method, `this` refers to the owner object. Alone, this refers to    the global object.
In a function, `this` refers to the global object.
In a function, in strict mode, `this` is undefined.
In an event, `this`    refers to the element that received the event.
Methods like `call()`,    and `apply()` can refer `this` to any object.

Answer (score 1):

The above code is not working because `this` is the `window` object in your case. Even if you manually created the button in HTML, then also, this inside the click handler would have been the `window` object.

A simple rule of thumb: `this` will be the owner of the context from where the function is being called.

Following is a small demo of the above hypothesis and the correct way to do this:

```js
function vTest(){
    console.log("this is same as window", this==window);
}

// Correct way to attach click event handlers to new elements.
function validate(e){
    console.log("validating");
    if(e.target.checked)
        console.log('Checked');
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var aCheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  aCheckbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  aCheckbox.addEventListener('click', validate);
  document.body.append(aCheckbox);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="vTest()"></input><br>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I created an example without the need to use `this`. It may be helpful.

```html
<div id="app"></div>
  <p>checked boxes: <span id="checkedBoxes">0</span></p>
  <script>
    const getCheckedAmount = () => {
      const checkedBoxes = document
        .querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

      const amountOfCheckedBoxes = Array
        .from(checkedBoxes).length;

      document
        .querySelector('#checkedBoxes')
        .innerHTML = amountOfCheckedBoxes;
    };

    const addCheckBoxes = () => {
      const todoApp = document.querySelector("#app");

      const checkboxes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        .map(
          number =>
            `<input type="checkbox" onclick="getCheckedAmount()">${number}</input>`
        )
        .join(" ");

        todoApp.innerHTML = `<div>${checkboxes}</div>`;
    };

    addCheckBoxes();
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is very helpful